# Objective-c: AppDelegate NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have an NSString that as an instance variable within my appdelegate as below:

distributedLCAAppDelegate.h:

```
@class distributedLCAViewController;

@interface distributedLCAAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
distributedLCAViewController *viewController;
NSString *token;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet distributedLCAViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *token;

@end
```

section from distributedLCAAppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation distributedLCAAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize token;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{ 
token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
token = [token substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [token length]-2)];
}
```

I need to be able to use this token variable within the view controller. Currently this is what I have:

section from within distributedLCAViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)switchWasActivated:(id)sender
{
    NSString *token2 = [[[distributedLCAAppDelegate alloc] token] autorelease];
}
```

However, token2 = "invalid cfstringref".

I initially tried declaring a public method called getToken, which just returned token. But I was getting the same problem in that case as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :** (UPDATED) (fixed)

```
NSString* token2 = ((distributedLCAAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).token;
```

Comment: Dr.Kameleon and @RIP: when I use your code I get an exec bad access when I try to print token2 using: NSLog(@"token2 = %@", token2);... and in the variable window, token2 is equal to something like "/System/Library/Frameworks/.."

Comment: I tried your updated code and I am getting the same error I am getting from every one else's code. it says "distributedLCAAppDelegate may not respond to delegate"... and your updated code is also giving me the error "property token not found on object of type id"

Comment: @exolaris Can you link your Application Delegate to the View Controller through Interface Builder (let's say, to `myDelegate`) and set it like `token2 = myDelegate.token`?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. =/ Would it be easy enough to explain or can you link me to tutorial on how (I couldn't find one)?

Comment: Dr.Kameleon's answer is correct but you have an additional bug. In `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`, you are assigning directly to the instance variable.  You are not going through the setter, so you are not copying the string. Change the references to `token` in that method to `self.token`. (You might want to use a temp local for all the manipulations except the last assignment.)

Comment: @Ken Thomases: What you said makes perfect sense, and I made the changes exactly as you suggested but I am still getting these two warnings/errors when I use Dr. Kameleon's code; 'distributedLCAAppDelegate' may not respond to 'delegate' and Property 'token' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: @exolaris I did just another small fix. Have a look!

Answer (score 2):

Try following -

```
- (IBAction)switchWasActivated:(id)sender {
    distributedLCAAppDelegate *delegate = (distributedLCAAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *token2 = delegate.token;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
distributedLCAAppDelegate* delegateobj = [(distributedLCAAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *token_ = delegateobj.token;
NSLog(@"token_ :%@",token_);
```

Try This , it should work

Comment: I am getting a warning on your first line "distributedLCAAppDelegate* delegateobj = [(distributedLCAAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];".. the warning says "distributedLCAAppDelegate may not respond to delegate".

Comment: and when i run the app. token_ = "variable is not a cfstring at this time."

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Files' Owner in "MainWindow.xib" if its delegate outlet is set to your distributedLCAAppDelegate? Just Ctrl-click on the yellow box-icon in Interface Builder.

Comment: Within IB, I clicked on the "distributedLCA App Delegate" (the yellow box) and under referencing outlets: delegate is connected to File's Owner. Is this what you were talking about?

FYI: under outlets: viewController is connected to distributedLCAViewController and window is connected to Window.
These are all of the connections I see under distributedLCA app delegate.

Comment: That seems to be ok, so that's not the problem here. Sorry, don't have another idea...